# add babel/polyfill in Gulp with Babelify and Browserify

Tags: gulp, browserify, polyfills, babeljs

I am using Babel and Browserify with Gulp. I want to add `babel-polyfill` into my project, but it is hard to find what I want to do on internet. 
This is `node_modules` I installed:

- vinyl-source-stream
- vinyl-buffer
- gulp
- gulp-sourcemaps
- browserify
- babelify
- babel-polyfill

And this is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return browserify('./source/app.js')
    .transform(babelify, { presets: ["es2015", "react"] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

I tried to add `babel-polyfill` like other people said but everything is not worked on me. I think it's getting harder and harder when I using gulp + babelify + browserify. next time, I should use webpack.

Anyway, back to the point, is there a way to add babel-polyfill into Gulp + Babelify + Browserify?

I spent hours but I'm still working on it.

Anyone gimme a advice and that will be very appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 'babel-polyfill' directly through script tag in the html.
Another way is require('babel-polyfill') is the begin of all your code.(Not in the gulp!)
See this.
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: lol, your point is correct. i wrote 'require('babel-polyfill') inside of my gulpfile! thanks!!!

Comment: This works, but this is not the answer to the question: I want to do the same thing... but WITHOUT adding a `require` to my code. I want to handle "babel-polyfill" through Browserify bundling: how can I do that?

Comment: `return browserify('./source/app.js')` change to `return browserify({ entries: [ require.resolve('babel-polyfill'), './source/app.js' ] }) ...` NOTE: you must npm babel-polyfill