# How do I replace @babel/polyfill for the latest Babel + Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, gulp-babel

Babel has droppped @babel/polyfill in one of its latest releases: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill. I am using `gulp-babel` and trying to make it support IE 9 and up:

```
gulp.task('js', () => {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.src.js.files)
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.js.dir))
});
```

I've also created `.browserslistrc` with the following content:

```
# Browsers that we support

defaults
```

However no matter what I do it still ignores IE 9 and up. What am I missing?

Comment: check this resources to see if works for you: 
https://gist.github.com/michaelkitson/eb4b4d40051d7b5c108872a5778ca96f
https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/27
there is an stackoverflow question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819419/add-babel-polyfill-in-gulp-with-babelify-and-browserify

Comment: Thanks, but those are for older versions of babel.